# How to access these type of json file in Android

Tags: android, json

here is my json file how to access the array in andriod

my.json

```
 [
            ["Sr No", " Blood Bank Name", " State", " District", " City", " Address ", "Pincode ", "Contact No "],
            ["1 ", "xyz bloodbank ", "xxx ", "yyy ", "xyz ", "123,xyz ", "0000 ", "1234567 "],
            ["2 ", "xz bloodbank ", "aaa ", "bb ", "bb ", "123, baa ", "111 ", "34567 "]
 ]
```

Comment: [
 ["Sr No", " Blood Bank Name", " State", " District", " City", " Address ", "Pincode ", "Contact No "],
 ["1 ", "xyz bloodbank ", "xxx ", "yyy ", "xyz ", "123,xyz ", "0000 ", "1234567 "],
 ["2 ", "xz bloodbank ", "aaa ", "bb ", "bb ", "123, baa ", "111 ", "34567 "]
]

Comment: its showing valid json

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String response = loadJSONFromAsset();

        try {
            JSONArray mainJsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < mainJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONArray childOne = mainJsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                JSONArray childTwo = mainJsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                JSONArray childThree = mainJsonArray.getJSONArray(i);

                arrayOne = new String[childOne.length()];
                for (int j = 0; j < childOne.length(); j++) {
                    arrayOne[j] = childOne.getString(j);
                }


                arrayTwo= new String[childTwo.length()];
                for (int j = 0; j < childTwo.length(); j++) {
                    arrayTwo[j] = childTwo.getString(j);
                }

                arrayThree= new String[childThree.length()];
                for (int j = 0; j < childThree.length(); j++) {
                    arrayThree[j] = childThree.getString(j);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOne.length; j++) {
            Log.e("VALUE1",arrayOne[j] );
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++) {
            Log.e("VALUE2",arrayTwo[j] );
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayThree.length; j++) {
            Log.e("VALUE3",arrayThree[j] );
        }



    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("myjson.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank u soo much its worked!!! !-Nilesh Rathod

Comment: @PrabhuBhuvaneshwar welcome happy to help

Comment: yaa sure big thumbs up!!!